# extract local time in a specific format using boost library

Tags: c++, time, boost

I try  to extract local time including time zone and format this in a format similar to the following
***2019-11-06T00:39:21.25+02:00***  with precision of milliseconds.
Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html)? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles, I stuck how to get local time and day and then using facet to  get the correct format

Comment: Please show a [mre] of what you have tried and show the problem you are having